# Setting up PHPUnit in PhpStorm using WSL-2 and Docker: Can not parse PHPUnit version output: Could not open input file

Tags: docker-compose, phpunit, phpstorm, wsl-2

I am having problem setting up PHPUnit with PhpStorm on my Windows 10 Professional using WSL-2 (Ubuntu), developing a docker-compose PHP app using Composer.

I have successfully configured the path to the Composer autoload.php:
[image]

It is finding the path to the actual PHPUnit but showing an error:

```
Can not parse PHPUnit version output: Could not open input file: /var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

[image]

I would guess there is a problem with file permissions.

Comment: Please share more details. The given path looks strange to me - why not use `/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit` as usual?

Comment: Also, what version of PhpStorm, Docker Desktop are you using?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without looking at the docker-compose.yml file and everything that is necessary to build the service you are using to run PHPUnit. The best choice here would be contacting PhpStorm support via Help | Contact Support.

Answer (score 0):

the solutionn was to enable "Use Docker Compose V2" in the Docker Desktop Settings:

[image]